# how get <img src=''> in xml parsing for rss feed

Tags: android

how get the url `<img src=''>` a rss feed and open on  in android

```
<description>
<img src="http://static.ibnlive.in.com/ibnlive/pix/sitepix/03_2010/google_new_630_90x62.jpg" alt="REDIRECTED: Google shut its Chinese portal over censorship and visitors were being redirected to Hong Kong-based site." title="REDIRECTED: Google shut its Chinese portal over censorship and visitors were being redirected to Hong Kong-based site." border="0" width="70" height="50" align="left" hspace="5"/>The company joins Google in protesting cyber attacks and censorship in China.
</description>
```

Comment: use JSoup library or XML Parser

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get an `URL` from the `XML` above, you can try to use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) library:

```
String input = "<description>\n" +
            "<img src=\"http://static.ibnlive.in.com/ibnlive/pix/sitepix/03_2010/google_new_630_90x62.jpg\"" +
            " alt=\"REDIRECTED: Google shut its Chinese portal over censorship and visitors were being redirected" +
            " to Hong Kong-based site.\" title=\"REDIRECTED: Google shut its Chinese portal" +
            " over censorship and visitors were being redirected to Hong Kong-based site.\"" +
            " border=\"0\" width=\"70\" height=\"50\" align=\"left\" hspace=\"5\"/>The company" +
            " joins Google in protesting cyber attacks and censorship in China.\n" +
            "</description>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(input);
String output = document.select("img").first().attr("src");
```

Comment: <description>
<img src="http://static.ibnlive.in.com/ibnlive/pix/sitepix/03_2010/google_new_630_90x62.jpg" alt="REDIRECTED: Google shut its Chinese portal over censorship and visitors were being redirected to Hong Kong-based site." title="REDIRECTED: Google shut its Chinese portal over censorship and visitors were being redirected to Hong Kong-based site." border="0" width="70" height="50" align="left" hspace="5"/>The company joins Google in protesting cyber attacks and censorship in China.
</description> i want to store in string  ?can i use xml paring for img?

Comment: @Sanjay please explain in a better way

Comment: i want image between these tag  <description><img src ="img url"></description>     i already done this using JSoup but i wnat to do this using xml?how can i do this plz help me

Comment: @Sanjay so you want to load data from external source (.xml file, I suppose), that use XML Parser and get the necessary text?

Answer (score 1):

first you should get description string with RssParser and then send that string to this method.  YOU DON'T NEED TO LIBRARY. of course first you should replace " with ' for match your example with my answer and also choose an special word that just exist in your img url for "equals" in my code. like "pix" word that exist in your question.

```
private String helperString(String str) {
    String[] strings = str.split("'");
    for (String string: strings) {
        Log.i("STR", "string : " + string);
        String[] newString = string.split("/");
        for (String a: newString) {
            if (a.equals("images")){  //in your question pix or other words
                Log.i("URL", "Image Url is : " + string);
                return string;
            }
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```